# How can i apply callback to get the http response in a method

Tags: javascript, callback

I am attempting to write a method so that i pass the url and application name and it return the response. I read that I can apply callback to resolve this but I am not able to resolve the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Please find below my code snippet.

```
var response = getResponse(url,applicationName)
console.log("response from getResponse \n" +response);

function getResponse(url,applicationName){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    "application": applicationName  
}));
xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}
return xhr.responseText;
}
```

Comment: You are returning xhr.responseText before it has been set. So it always returns null. You may want to return a Promise from your function. Or better use the fetch API ( A promise based version of XMLHttpRequest ).

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onreadystatechange method to handle XHR responses, try this:

```js
//XHR POST
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;                             // creates new object
const url = 'https://api-to-call.com/endpoint';
const data = JSON.stringify({"application": applicationName});              // converts data to a string

xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    return xhr.response;
  }
}
xhr.open('POST', url);      // opens request
xhr.send(data);                         // sends object
```

Comment: how this solution is different? i still cant xhr.response from the method

Comment: check out xhr.onreadystatechange: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

Comment: function getResponse(url,applicationName){
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;                             // creates new object
const data = JSON.stringify({"application": applicationName});              // converts data to a string
 var response ;

xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    response =  xhr.response;
  }
}
xhr.open('POST', url);      // opens request
xhr.send(data);
return response;
}. This is not working

Answer (score 0):

you should use promise instead of callback and do something like that.

```js
const url = "https://httpbin.org/post";
const applicationName = "test";
getResponse(url, applicationName)
  .then(response => { 
    //work here, not outside
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })

function getResponse(url, applicationName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
      "application": applicationName
    }));
    xhr.onload = function() {
      // print JSON response
      if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) { // if valid
        // work here 
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.response.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'));
        const data = JSON.parse(response.data.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'));
        resolve(data);
      }
      reject(xhr.response); // reject and return the response if not valid
    }
  })

}
```

If you want to learn more about asynchronous https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Concepts, I invite you to go to this website to learn a little more about the promise.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong in this but I am still getting null for this.

Comment: can you show us the new modification that you did

Comment: var res ;
getResponse(url,applicationName).then(response =>{
        console.log(response)
        res = response;
})
console.log(res)

function getResponse(url, applicationName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", url, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      xhr.onload = function() {
          resolve(xhr.responseText);
        }
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            "application": applicationName
          }));
    })
  
  }.   console.log(res) is null

Comment: ok, it's totally normal that res return `null`, you need to understand that you will receive a response **asynchronously**, like @RobMonhemius  told you, you need to wait the response to be set. For that, you need to work inside the function `then`

Comment: I think I am not able to follow this concept here. Could you please tell me what i should do in this code so that i dont get the res null?

Comment: nothing, you just need to work inside the function `then` and not outside, if you try to log `res` outside the function you will get a `null` since the response is not set.

Answer (score 0):

The callback is executed after the code returned xhr.responseText. So that means xhr.responseText returns null.

I would recommend using the fetch API opposed to the older XMLHttpRequest you are using now. The fetch API is basically a Promise based XMLHttpRequest.

Your function would look something like:

```js
async function getResponse( url, applicationName ) {
  const json = JSON.stringify({
    "application": applicationName  
  });
  return fetch( url, {method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json'}, body: json} );
}

// access like this

getResponse( url, applicationName)
.then( response => { console.log(response) });

async function someFunction( url, applicationName ) {
  // or pause the code while the request is fetched by using await, note that you need to be in a function that is declared async to use this approach.
  const response = await getResponse( url, applicationName );
}
```

Fetch documentation can be found at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch